# bias–variance decomposition related to median?

Tags: variance, bias, estimators, median, mse

In evaluating or designing an estimator $\hat\theta$ of a population parameter $\theta$, the most common approach is to look at its bias,
$\operatorname{E} \hat\theta - \theta$,
its variance,
$\operatorname{E} \left(\hat\theta - \operatorname{E}\hat\theta \right)^2$,
and its mean squared error,
$\operatorname{E} \left(\hat\theta - \theta \right)^2$.
It can be shown that the mean squared error is equal to the sum of the squared bias and the variance. Bias, variance, and mean squared error form a triplet of estimator properties that complement each other. Estimators are chosen for unbiasedness, minimum variance given unbiasedness, or minimum mean squared error.

Instead of mean-bias one can also look at median-bias, $\operatorname{median} \hat\theta - \theta$. Are there two other properties that "complement" median-bias, like variance and mean squared error do for mean-bias? Can a similar decomposition be formulated for that triplet? I'm guessing candidates would be mean/median absolute deviation/error.